# Show header widget only on one page

Tags: wordpress, header, show, visible

I'm working with Wordpress on the website www.stuff-n-uff.be, and there's a header widget that I only want to show on the homepage. Now I've already made this work, but there's one problem; after a little while the header widget disappears at all times.

Here's my code:

```
body div.header-widget-region {
height: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}

nav.woocommerce-breadcrumb {
margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

.home.archive.post-type-archive.post-type-archive-product.logged-in.admin-bar.custom-background.woocommerce.woocommerce-page.right-sidebar.woocommerce-active.has-site-logo.customize-support div.header-widget-region {
height: 273px;
visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could tag the coding language that this was done in.

Answer (score 1):

you have to do php code for this widget.

```
<?php 
  if(is_front_page()):
    //place your widget here
  endif;
?>
```